# Master Detail app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I've managed to read some values into a table view and display them in the Master View of a SplitViewController.

What I would like to do is to tap on a row of the Master View and display the details on the detailViewController but in a custom cell of a TableView which has a label and a textfield.

When I tap on the row in the MasterView table, I can't seem to get the detail to populate the detailview custom cell.

I tried something like

```
if  (indexPath.row == 0) {
    lbPerson.text = @"Name";
    tfPerson.text = @"John";
    tfPaciente.placeholder = @"Name";
}else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
    lbPerson.text = @"Address";
    tfPerson.text = @"Street blabla";
    tfPerson.placeholder = @"Address";
}
```

but I am not sure where to place my code and how to update my detailview tableview when I tap my masterview table

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your detailView you should have "id detailItem", this is then set in the delegate method :

-(void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem {

```
if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {

    _detailItem = [newDetailItem retain]; 

    // Update the view.
    [self configureView];
}
```

}

-(void)configureView {

```
// Update the user interface for the detail item.
if (self.detailItem) {
   //do something ... reload tableview or change values etc 
}
```

}

To call this method in your MasterView implement something like this:

-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

```
self.YOURDETAILVIEWCONTROLLER.detailItem = @"Example";
self.YOURDETAILVIEWCONTROLLER.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You Pressed Row %d", indexPath.row];
```

}

This will call the first method that set the detail view, obviously through this detail item you can set properties of the detailView.